# Spring WebFlux and WebSocket

Tags: javascript, java, spring, websocket, spring-webflux

I am trying to add WebSocket functionality to an existing application which uses Spring WebFlux. It uses:

- Spring boot 2.2.1.RELEASE
- Tomcat container
- Configured to serve jsp pages

When I try to connect to it through JavaScript (from inside a jsp page) I am receiving the error "*failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404*"

I noted that if I create a controller class mapping url '/ws/event-emitter' (the one mapped in my websocket configuration) accepting GET requests, it receives the requests from Javascript call when it tries to open the websocket connection, which made me more confused.

What am I missing?

After read some tutorials on the Internet I set my configuration as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.2.1.RELEASE
 

br.com.samsung
monitor
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
monitor
Health Check Monitor

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MongoDB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
        <version>Lovelace-SR9</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```
@Configuration
public class ReactiveWebSocketConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler;

    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping webSocketHandlerMapping() {
        Map<String, WebSocketHandler> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("/ws/event-emitter", webSocketHandler);

        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        handlerMapping.setUrlMap(map);
        return handlerMapping;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter(WebSocketService webSocketService) {
        return new WebSocketHandlerAdapter(webSocketService);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketService webSocketService() {
        TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy strategy = new TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy();
        strategy.setMaxSessionIdleTimeout(0L);
        return new HandshakeWebSocketService(strategy);
    }

}
```

and the Web socket handler class

```
@Component
public class ReactiveWebSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

    private static final ObjectMapper json = new ObjectMapper();

    private Flux<String> eventFlux = Flux.generate(sink -> {
        Event event = new Event(randomUUID().toString(), now().toString());
        try {
            sink.next(json.writeValueAsString(event));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            sink.error(e);
        }
    });

    private Flux<String> intervalFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(1000L))
      .zipWith(eventFlux, (time, event) -> event);

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) {
        return webSocketSession.send(intervalFlux
          .map(webSocketSession::textMessage))
          .and(webSocketSession.receive()
            .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText).log());
    }

}
```

```js
var clientWebSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:6600/ws/event-emitter");
clientWebSocket.onopen = function() {
  console.log("clientWebSocket.onopen", clientWebSocket);
  console.log("clientWebSocket.readyState", "websocketstatus");
  clientWebSocket.send("event-me-from-browser");
}
clientWebSocket.onclose = function(error) {
  console.log("clientWebSocket.onclose", clientWebSocket, error);
  events("Closing connection");
}
clientWebSocket.onerror = function(error) {
  console.log("clientWebSocket.onerror", clientWebSocket, error);
  events("An error occured");
}
clientWebSocket.onmessage = function(error) {
  console.log("clientWebSocket.onmessage", clientWebSocket, error);
  events(error.data);
}

function events(responseEvent) {
  document.querySelector(".events").innerHTML += responseEvent + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set CORS configuration on your HandlerMapping?

Comment: are the ports correct?

Comment: @FelipeBonfante yes, I have already tried CORS configuration but no luck. Anyway my Javascript code is running from inside a jsp file the application itself is serving.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf yes, they are. I have changed the default 8080 port as I have another application using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could make it work removing *spring-boot-starter-web* and *tomcat-embed-jasper* dependencies. I suppose *spring-boot-starter-web* might conflict with *spring-boot-starter-webflux*.

Also I have changed my *ReactiveWebSocketConfiguration* class to set *WebSocketService* bean using *ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy* instead of *TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy*:

```
@Bean
public WebSocketService webSocketService() {
    return new HandshakeWebSocketService(new ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy());
}
```

After those changes my jsp pages stopped working as my web container changed from Tomcat to Netty Web Server.
I had to use Thymeleaf (added *spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf* dependency, configured its basic strucute and converted my pages to .html files) instead of traditional jsp.

I have opted to change from traditional jsp to Thymeleaf due to time constraints as my application has few and simple pages.

I have created a very simple project with all those configuration including a dummy page connecting to the websocket via javascript.

https://github.com/atilio-araujo/spring-webflux-websocket

Answer (score 4):

## Spring WebFlux WebSocket:

Just adding this answer for people who are trying to achieve `websocket` with `webflux`.

1. The OP has both `web` and `webflux` dependencies for some reason. However you just need `WebFlux` dependency only.
2. Implement a WebSocketHandler

```
    @Service
    public class WebFluxWebSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {
    
        @Override
        public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) {
            Flux<WebSocketMessage> stringFlux = webSocketSession.receive()
                    .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                    .map(String::toUpperCase)
                    .map(webSocketSession::textMessage);
            return webSocketSession.send(stringFlux);
        }
    
    }
```

3. Add a path - handler mapping. Here the handler is an instance of the websockethandler.

```
     @Bean
       public HandlerMapping handlerMapping(){
           Map<String, WebFluxWebSocketHandler> handlerMap = Map.of(
                   "/test", handler
           );
           return new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping(handlerMap, 1);
       }
```

That's it! Now the client should be able to connect to `ws://localhost:8080/test`

Check here for more info - https://www.vinsguru.com/spring-webflux-websocket/

Comment: I would like to ask can we log client information in your example by ServerHttpRequest?  how in the websocket webflux we can log client information?